# remove kernel not created using .deb file

Tags: kernel, uninstall

i by mistake installed kernel in Ubuntu 11.04 using "make" command and didn't created proper ".deb" file.

now i want to remove that image of kernel and since i didn't created using .deb file, i don't see the header file in synaptic or ubuntu-tweak, but it is there in grub and /boot folder.

please tell me what is the best way i can remove kernel which i installed using make command?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why you have an Unsupported version of Ubuntu ? In case you don't know Ubuntu 11.04 has reached EOL(End Of Life) long time ago. See [the table here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

About the original question now:

You can try

```
sudo make uninstall
```

that might solve your problem. Of course you have to remember the `make install` commands your already ran.

If above is not helpful, you can try

```
make -n install
```

this will show you the steps that software would take to install itself. This can be helpful and you can try to reverse those steps.

Lastly you can manually remove the related paths:

Delete

```
/boot/vmlinuz*KERNEL-VERSION* 
/boot/initrd*KERNEL-VERSION* 
/boot/System-map*KERNEL-VERSION* 
/boot/config-*KERNEL-VERSION* 
/lib/modules/*KERNEL-VERSION*/
```

and then

```
sudo update-grub
```